# How to know what JSON URI returns?

Tags: android, json, arrays

Some URIs return a `JSONObject` object while others return a `JSONArray`. I usually put everything into `JSONArray` and so far I had no exceptions. Of course, this is not the safest way so:

How to know what JSON URI returns?

Can I "guess" this via the type of URI or there is a better way? When I say the type of URI, look at Twitter's URI like `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=android` where I can "guess" it returns a `JSONArray`. But such "guessing" prevents me to put anything into a `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be specified in the [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), if you don't want to count on it, you can use try-catch to find the actual type.

Comment: Yes, but some API docs are horrible and with no info. Not to say that Philipp's solution is faster.

Comment: Have fun then, but in this specific case the docs seems very clear (and it's my first time I'm looking at them)

Comment: +1 on reading the docs -- I'd even suggest to fail on unexpected API responses instead of guessing what the data might be.

Comment: Guys, twitter JSON URI was just an example :). But thanks for advices

Comment: +1 for try/catch. Exactly what catching exceptions is all about. So many people believe an exception is a terrible error when in many cases using try/catch can be an elegant way of simply testing for certain conditions.

Comment: The important thing in my opinion is that you should not try and be too dynamic, because you will end up with big clumsy unreadable and unmaintainable code. Web APIs should be treaded as normal SW API, with defined input and return values. Handling weird things is no-good.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `org.json` classes. They work, but are pretty basic.

Try [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), it has a much richer and arguably nicer(*) API:

```
String|Reader|JsonReader input = ...
JsonElement json = new JsonParser(input).parse();
if (json.isJsonArray()) {
  JsonArray array = json.asJsonArray();
  ...
} else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
  JsonObject object = json.asJsonObject();
  ...
}
```

Instead of the `is`/`as` methods, you can also use `instanceof JsonObject/Array` and regular java casts.

(*) just one example: Gson's [`JsonArray`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html) gives you foreach loops by being an `Iterable<JsonElement>` vs. the `get(int)` orgy that is `org.json.JSONArray`